# Express regexp routing for optional path

Tags: regex, node.js, express

Now I'm trying to route to some optional path like this.

```
router.get('/foo/bar(.*)', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("baz");
});
```

To accept any strings after "bar", I've wrote this code and test it, but this did not work. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must try this following Path pattern:

```
// will match paths starting with /foo/bar and after this any string
router.get('/foo/bar*', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("baz");
});
```

Its working for me. See details on [**Express Doc**](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use)

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the `.`

```
router.get('/foo/bar(\.*)', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("baz");
});
```

Comment: I've tried, but it did not work. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of valid/invalid routes?